# Understanding P-Values in R - easy

Tags: r, p-value

When looking at the table of coefficients for models it lists `.`, `*`, `**`, or `***` next to the P-values.

They state this at the bottom (but I find this is what actually confuses me):

`Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1`

One of my models has a P value of 0.00506 with `**`. But that doesn't make sense to me according to the line above. I think I've made it a lot more confusing than it actually is!

So in painfully simple terms what do the `*`, `**`, `***`'s equate to?

Comment: So you understand what happened with the edits—before you could finish editing I and another already edited your asterisk formatting away. On SO, asterisks translate to italics, so it's necessary to wrap them in grave ticks (\`\`) or escape them with a backslash. Your eventual edit with "asterix" (it's "asterisk" by the way) wasn't ideal so I rolled it back.

Comment: Honestly, you're probably better off paying absolutely no attention to the stars (i.e. asterisks) at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This shows the cutpoints (the numbers) and the number of stars if the pvalue is between the cutpoints on either side of the stars so:

```
 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

means that

- if the pvalue is between 0 and 0.001 then it will have 3 stars,
- if it is between 0.001 and 0.01 it will have 2 stars,
- if it is between 0.01 and 0.05 it will have 1 star,
- if it is between 0.05 and 0.1 it will have a dot and
- if it is between 0.1 and 1 it will not have anything (just a space).

0.00506 is between 0.001 and 0.01 so it has 2 stars.

Look at the source code to the function `printCoefmat` to see the actual code that does it. You can find it [here](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/176a4bb90d00c0e0738210703fef8a626a239f38/src/library/stats/R/anova.R) .

Comment: Thank you so much, now it makes perfect sense!!